# How to set custom height and width for a dialog box in android

Tags: java, android

How to set custom height and width for this dialog box directly into the main activity file. I tried one method but it only matches the parent height and width

```
public void onBackPressed()
    {

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
        builder.setTitle(R.string.app_name);
        builder.setIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
        builder.setMessage("Please Help Us Grow before leaving!")
                .setCancelable(false)
     .setPositiveButton("Exit", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        finish();
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton("Share our app", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                        Intent sendIntent = new Intent(); sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                        sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Download it now: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.app.package");
                        sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
                        sendIntent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
                        startActivity(sendIntent);
                    }
                });
        AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
        alertDialog.show();
        WindowManager.LayoutParams layoutParams = new WindowManager.LayoutParams();
        layoutParams.copyFrom(alertDialog.getWindow().getAttributes());
        layoutParams.width = WindowManager.LayoutParams(100);
        layoutParams.height = WindowManager.LayoutParams(100);
        alertDialog.getWindow().setAttributes(layoutParams);
```

Comment: Use DialogFragment with custom layout.

Answer (score 0):

set layout size after show();

```
alertDialog.show();
alertDialog.getWindow().setLayout(600, 400); //Controlling width and height.
```

p.s] change text size

```
AlertDialog dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setMessage("Hello world").show();
// you can get id from dialog xml.
TextView textView = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(android.R.id.message);
textView.setTextSize(40);
```

Comment: is there any way to set fontsize also?? because all text looks in a little small size

Comment: check my changed answer

Answer (score 0):

You can set it as `alertDialog.getWindow().setLayout(600, 400);`and also you can set it as

```
    WindowManager.LayoutParams layoutParams = new WindowManager.LayoutParams();
    layoutParams.copyFrom(alertDialog.getWindow().getAttributes());
    layoutParams.width = 150;
    layoutParams.height = 500;
    layoutParams.x=-180;
    layoutParams.y=100;
    alertDialog.getWindow().setAttributes(layoutParams);
```